# CloneNode with new ID JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using the below script to drag an existing div onto another, I'd like to also assign a new random ID to the cloned one so there are no conflicts. Maybe concatenate "newdiv" with the original ID so that it's unique.

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}

</script>
```

Comment: so what is the issue? clone the element into a variable and set the id.

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure how to do that with this script. Fairly new to JS.

Comment: `var foo = ....cloneNode()`